# Units of gBuffer from rgeos package

Tags: r, buffer, rgeos

I have this polygon:

```
library(maptools); library(sp)
setwd(system.file("shapes", package="maptools")) 
columbus <- readShapeSpatial("columbus.shp")

proj4string(columbus) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")
columbus <- spTransform(columbus, CRS("+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"))
```

I need to buffer 1km around the polygon, so I tried this:

```
library(rgeos)
gBuffer(columbus, width = 1000)
```

Could someone tell me if buffering by `width=1000` is buffering by 1km?

Comment: Yes your map projection is in units of metres.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on the units. If you are using metric system (like UTM), than 1000 is indeed 1 km. If the units are in WGS (degrees), than you have to first convert your data to metric system (`spTranspform` in `rgdal` package) and then you can use `gBuffer` with 1000 width.

Columbus data are in WGS (you can see it by the fact, that coordinates are around 9 or 10).

Therefore you have to transforms them. I am not sure, which CRS you use, but it seems to be metric, so in that case, width 1000 equal to 1 km.